# imread function doesn't work in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am new to Image processing and learning matlab. Actually till now I have used matlab cloud version where uploading an image was directly possible and didn't face any issue. But now I am facing an extreme problem of uploading an image in matlab offline version software.

1. I imported an image by using "import data"
2. Then I wrote this command

> h = imread( 'digi1.jpg');

3. But my first line didn't run saying digi1 doesn't exist.

Comment: Does `digi1.jpg` exist in your working directory?  Go to your command prompt and type in `ls`, push ENTER and see if `digi1.jpg` is there.  Doing `import data` is independent of the `imread` error.  `import data` simply imports data into your workspace and you can use the data directly from there.  If it `digi1.jpg` isn't there, you need to change the working directory to where `digi1.jpg` is located.  Right now, this is assuming a local path.  You can override this by providing the full path to your image.  This way, you can load in the image independent of your working directory location.

Comment: @rayryeng I have saved the workspace  as a name.mat folder in the same directory. And later I changed the name to digi1.jpg. But it's giving an error "unable to determine file format."

Comment: Oops really silly of mine. But thank you for the help. I firstly loaded the pic with.                       load name.mat then used imwrite to create the new image. Thank you so much for the help it's working now.. :)

Comment: That's totally fine.  It happens to all of us.  Can I write an answer for you to accept?

Comment: Yeag sure. Definitely I will accept :)

Comment: Thanks :) writing now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing comes from saving the data to a MATLAB data file, renaming the file with a `.jpg` extension and trying to use `imread` to read in the data.

This unfortunately doesn't work.  You can't change the file type of your data from `.mat` to `.jpg`. All you're doing is changing what the name of the file is. You're not changing the **contents of the file**.  Changing the file extension and name of the file does not mean that the contents will change.  Renaming it to `digi1.jpg` would still make this file a MATLAB MAT file which you can only read with software that can read these files (Python, R, and yes MATLAB of course).

As such, try using `load name.mat` (which is the name of your MAT file) in the command prompt.  This should give you the image already loaded into the workspace.  Whatever that variable is called, use `imwrite` to save the image to file.

Assuming that the image was stored in a variable called `A`, do something like this:

```
>> load name.mat
>> imwrite(A, 'digi1.jpg');
```

Make sure `name.mat` is in the current working directory of where you are trying to run the above code.  You should now get an image saved on your disk.  However, I would recommend you use something lossless instead of JPG if you want to maintain the quality of your image.  Try using PNG instead, so save your image as a `.png` rather than `.jpg`.